# Rails 4: manipulate link_to remote POST query string parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following link_to method:

```
link_to "", votes_path(vote: { post_id: post.id, up: true}), method: :post, remote: true
```

and I'm trying to intercept the triggered AJAX call to manipulate the POST parameters.
With a GET request this was quite easy because the parameters are stored under data:

```
$('#my_link').bind('ajax:before', function() {
  $(this).data('params', { foo: 'bar' })
});
```

but that's not the case for POST request.
Can someone tell me where the POST parameters are stored?

Comment: Have you tried `ajax:beforeSend` instead?

Comment: doesn't make a difference, the link object stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind I just found out myself.

What you have to do is just manipulate the href attribute from the first object in the link array:

```
$('#my_link').bind('ajax:before', function() {
  $(this).first().attr('href', href + "&vote[custom_param]=customvalue");
});
```